# Restoring a DataBase

Tags: sql-server-2008, backup-restoration

i have two deferent Servers databases connections , let say `j` and `k`   .. and i have

`backup data file` in `j`, i named it `jtok.bak`  ..

now , i am trying to restore a database in `k` from  `jtok.bak` , the database name is `kkk` ...

so ... is there a way to do that ?

Comment: So you're trying to restore a database backup named jtok.bak from server j to a datbase on server k named kkk? Yes, there is a way to do that. Would you like specifics on how to do it?

Comment: ya ya .. of course..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click your 'kkk' database and go to Tasks -> Restore -> Database. Choose the From Device option and browse to your backup file. Click on the Options page and select Overwrite the existing database. Below that checkbox is an area where you can make sure the data and log files are in the right spot. Once everything is set up how you want it just click OK and it should restore.

Comment: i tried that .. and it is not working , becouse the backup file on `j` server and dosen't appear on `k` server ..!!

Comment: and of course i am trying to restore it on `k` server ...

Comment: Well you'll need to put the backup file on the k server. You could do this through some sort of shared folder, usb, etc...